# Space in ScriptAlias in httpd.conf prevents start of fcgi process

Tags: apache2, mod-fcgid

I am having troubles with the current apache httpd (2.2.21) and mod_fcgid (2.3.6) versions. In my project, it is possible that the ScriptAlias directive in the httpd.conf can contain spaces because operating system paths can contain them. This use to work with older httpd and fcgid versions. But since we switched to the current versions, it doesn't work anymore. If the path of the ScriptAlias contain a space and mod_fcgid wants to start my fcgi process, I get the following error log:

```
326 [Fri Jan 06 11:30:01 2012] [notice] Apache/2.2.21 (Unix) mod_fcgid/2.3.6 configured -- resuming normal operations

327 [Fri Jan 06 11:30:03 2012] [warn] [client 77.58.246.206] (104)Connection reset by peer: mod_fcgid: error reading data from FastCGI server

328 [Fri Jan 06 11:30:03 2012] [error] [client 77.58.246.206] Premature end of script headers: somename.fcgi
```

Is this a known problem? I couldn't find anything on Google.

Best
David

Comment: I can bypass the problem by downgrading mod_fcgid. That means, the problem was introduce in one of the latest mod_fcgid versions.

Comment: I think this post is more serverfault related, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, unfortunately the copy of `mod_fcgid` for Apache 2.2.21 does not work with paths that have spaces. The [bug](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=51194) has been committed and should be resolved in newer versions, so you can update, or you can use the 8.3 short-name of the path.